# WildFly30, SpringBoot 3: Cannot invoke "org.jboss.jandex.FieldInternal.type()" because "field" is null"

Tags: spring-boot, jboss, wildfly, java-21

Enviroment:

- WildFly30
- Java 21
- Spring Boot 3.2.0

After creating the War file i tried to deploy it but got following exception:

```
15:14:42,252 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "duengeportal-rest-api.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"duengeportal-rest-api.war\".STRUCTURE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment \"duengeportal-rest-api.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYSRV0156: Failed to index deployment root for annotations
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke \"org.jboss.jandex.FieldInternal.type()\" because \"field\" is null"}}
15:14:42,252 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "duengeportal-rest-api.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"duengeportal-rest-api.war\".STRUCTURE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment \"duengeportal-rest-api.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYSRV0156: Failed to index deployment root for annotations
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke \"org.jboss.jandex.FieldInternal.type()\" because \"field\" is null"}}
15:14:42,254 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "duengeportal-rest-api.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"duengeportal-rest-api.war\".STRUCTURE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment \"duengeportal-rest-api.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYSRV0156: Failed to index deployment root for annotations
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke \"org.jboss.jandex.FieldInternal.type()\" because \"field\" is null"}}
15:14:42,258 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment duengeportal-rest-api.war (runtime-name: duengeportal-rest-api.war) in 4ms
[2023-12-12 03:14:42,295] Artifact duengeportal-rest-api.war: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
[2023-12-12 03:14:42,296] Artifact duengeportal-rest-api.war: java.lang.Exception: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"duengeportal-rest-api.war\".STRUCTURE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment \"duengeportal-rest-api.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYSRV0156: Failed to index deployment root for annotations
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke \"org.jboss.jandex.FieldInternal.type()\" because \"field\" is null"}}
```

Comment: Got the same issue. I found it related to jar files that do not contain META-INF/module-info.class, indexation module information.
My case was with ojdbc11-23.3.0.23.09.jar jar file. 
Go an errors such: WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0003: Could not index class oracle/jdbc/proxy/

But , I would like to bypass this indexation PHASE. Can someone help ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are upgrading Spring Boot or just migrating to a more recent WildFly server, but check if what [Francesco Marchioni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/475635/francesco-marchioni) said helps ([How to run Spring Boot applications on WildFly](https://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/spring/spring-boot-hello-world-on-wildfly/?utm_content=cmp-true)):

> The removal of the **org.jboss.vfs** module in **WildFy 28** presents a
> problem for Spring deployments, as Spring Boot uses the resource
> protocol “vfs” when scanning for configuration resources. To avoid
> this issue, it is recommended that the org.jboss.vfs module be added
> as a dependency for deployments, which will enable Spring deployments
> to function properly without having to add a private module dependency
> to the deployment.

So if you are using maven add the folloing dependency to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-vfs</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.17.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Add jboss-deployment-structure.xml to src/main/webapp/WEB-INF

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <deployment>
      <dependencies>
         <module name="org.jboss.vfs" />
      </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I'm using WildFly29 and this worked for me.