# Deployment issues when upgrading from JBoss 4.2.3 to Wildfly 30

Tags: jboss, wildfly

I recently am assigned to upgrade an application originally deployed on JBoss 4.2.3 (!) to the newest equivalent.  Naturally it means Wildfly 30.

Thanks to the app being a Maven project I hadn't had *too* much difficulties updating the libraries  and Spring definitions.

It's now encountering this error:  (in reality "(my WAR name)" is obviously some rational name)

```
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."(my WAR name).war".STRUCTURE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."(my WAR name).war".STRUCTURE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "(my WAR name).war"
    at org.jboss.as.server@22.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:178)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1617)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1580)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1438)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYSRV0156: Failed to index deployment root for annotations
    at org.jboss.as.server@22.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.annotation.ResourceRootIndexer.indexResourceRoot(ResourceRootIndexer.java:93)
    at org.jboss.as.server@22.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.annotation.AnnotationIndexProcessor.deploy(AnnotationIndexProcessor.java:34)
    at org.jboss.as.server@22.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:171)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.jboss.jandex.FieldInternal.type()" because "field" is null
    at io.smallrye.jandex//org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.propagateTypeVariables(Indexer.java:2894)
    at io.smallrye.jandex//org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.complete(Indexer.java:2551)
    at org.jboss.as.server@22.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.annotation.ResourceRootIndexer.indexResourceRoot(ResourceRootIndexer.java:89)
    ... 10 more
```

I consider myself lucky to see someone asking something similar ([question 77646795](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77646795/wildfly30-springboot-3-cannot-invoke-org-jboss-jandex-fieldinternal-type-b)), but not-so-luckily my issue isn't resolved after following the given answer (i.e. adding "jboss-deployment-structure.xml" and importing "org.jboss.vfs" library).

I tried to add "jboss-deployment-structure.xml" under the web application's "src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/" folder, and added import of "org.jboss.vfs" in both that XML and the "pom.xml" files.  However, it only showed a shorter error:

```
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"(my WAR name).war\".STRUCTURE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment \"(my WAR name).war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYSRV0156: Failed to index deployment root for annotations
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException"}}
```

Any ideas?  Specifically,

1. what config files / elements / properties am I missing?
2. what additional information do I need to provide here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wouldn't go all the way to Jakarta EE 10 in a one big leap and would go to WildFly 26 first. You should make sure that you don't have any Java EE / Jakarta EE api jar in your deployment

Comment: What is the bytecode versoin?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins Sorry don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @ehsavoie A bit difficult for the latter sentence because the app itself does require EE api.  Also, what's the difference between WildFly 26 and 30?

Comment: The Java EE api should be provided with the implementation by the server not by the deployment so I'm not sure how this is a concern. WildFly 26 is Jakarta EE 8 / Java EE 8 and >= WildFly27 is Jakarta EE 10

Comment: What I mean, is what is your code compiled down to. The fact that it's a Jandex error means it's reading bytecode and the bytecode might simply be too old for Jandex to process. In other words are you compiling down to say Java 1.4?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins No, I didn't down-compile the code.  I set the code level to 17.  Admittedly some of the original libraries were old, but I am trying my best to update as many of them as possible, in some cases re-visiting from the sources and re-compiling with updated imports as necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eventually I got past this stage by downgrading ojdbc11 reference.

It's hinted from the recent WildFly 30 question ([WildFly30, SpringBoot 3: Cannot invoke "org.jboss.jandex.FieldInternal.type()" because "field" is null"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77646795/wildfly30-springboot-3-cannot-invoke-org-jboss-jandex-fieldinternal-type-b))

Apparently its newest version (23.3.0.23.09) has some jandex related issues (as indicated [on keycloak GitHub](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/25046)).

Now I meet some other Spring-related error but it seems they have been asked somewhere else so I think I can close this question.  Thanks for all your help.