# Spring 6 project still tries to load javax

Tags: spring, jakarta-migration

Moving on from [Question 77947044](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77947044/deployment-issues-when-upgrading-from-jboss-4-2-3-to-wildfly-30), I now have the Spring 6 project throwing `NoClassDefFoundError` exceptions regarding javax:

```
11:51:28,760 WARN  [org.jboss.modules.define] (MSC service thread 1-2) Failed to define class org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag in Module "deployment.{my WAR name}.war" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/form/AbstractHtmlElementTag (Module "deployment.{my WAR name}.war" from Service Module Loader): javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/DynamicAttributes
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1090)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:482)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:276)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:79)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:765)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:192)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1090)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:482)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:276)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:79)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:765)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:192)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@30.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.utils.ClassLoadingUtils.loadClass(ClassLoadingUtils.java:26)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@30.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.utils.ClassLoadingUtils.loadClass(ClassLoadingUtils.java:19)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@30.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:67)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@30.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:60)
    at org.jboss.as.server@22.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:171)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1617)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1580)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1438)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

```
11:51:29,277 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."{my WAR name}.war".undertow-deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."{my WAR name}.war".undertow-deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1609)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1438)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1363)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet (Module "deployment.{my WAR name}.war" from Service Module Loader): Failed to link org/springframework/web/servlet/FrameworkServlet (Module "deployment.{my WAR name}.war" from Service Module Loader): Failed to link org/springframework/web/servlet/HttpServletBean (Module "deployment.{my WAR name}.war" from Service Module Loader): javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1090)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:482)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:276)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:79)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:765)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:192)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1090)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:482)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:276)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:79)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:765)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:192)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1090)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:482)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:276)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:79)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:765)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:192)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@30.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.createServletConfig(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:634)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@30.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.start(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:270)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1617)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.5.2.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1580)
    ... 6 more
```

This is despite my best effort to get rid of every "javax" reference in favour of "jakarta", and my Spring library being up-to-date (6.1.3).

Appreciated if there's, say, a checklist for me to review my application.

EDIT 2024-02-26:

Regarding comment from @BalusC, here are some tools and technologies I am utilizing:

1. IDE = Eclipse 2023-12
2. JDK = 17
3. Spring = 6.1.3; Spring-security = 6.2.1; Spring-boot = 3.2.2
4. Maven compiler plugin 3.11.0; Maven WAR plugin = 3.4.0; Maven failsafe plugin 3.2.2

Also, I found that if I wrap it in EAR project, no such error occurs despite having identical library settings (We have a parent "configuration" project to manage all library import, and the web app project doesn't contain "version" in the pom.xml).  Rather, it simply deploys without error but the webapp doesn't run.

P.S. If I build a WAR file from the web app project, and deploy it onto a remote Wildfly 30.0.0 server, it also deploys without error, but no response if I try to access the web app.

Comment: You likely have a mix of spring library versions, some on 6x and some on 5x. Specifically, check the spring-web version on Spring 6x.

Comment: I don't know if you've already done that, but to migrate all the correct javax.* imports to jakarta.* ones, I recommend openwrite https://docs.openrewrite.org/recipes/java/migrate/jakarta/javaxmigrationtojakarta

Comment: @pochopsp Not sure how this can be done on Eclipse.

Comment: @BalusC Edited the question to address your concerns.

Comment: This still looks like there is a mix of Spring versions being used.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins thanks for your response.

Sorry I have committed a very low-level mistake.

For the case with the error I posted in this question, I simply deployed a wrong project which I no longer use.

The web application has always been embedded in the EAR project so it's deployed without error, just the webapp didn't run properly.

In this case should I post another question (after confirming the situation), or edit this question to reflect my newest obstacles?

Comment: Likely a new question I'd think since the topic would be different.

Comment: Well noted.  I'd close this one and possibly ask for deletion because the cause is a trivial mistake.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I have committed a very trivial mistake.

It turns out I simply deployed a wrong application which I no longer use.

The correct application turns out having no error on deployment, simply that it doesn't run as expected.  I will post another question if necessary.

Since this question is caused by a trivial mistake I wish to know if this question qualifies deletion.  Sorry for the inconvenience caused.